# Is shutdown-hook a good practice?

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

I have a `Service` that makes requests via a `RestClient`.

What is the Java best practice between:

1. Opening and closing the connection every time I make a request
2. Opening the connection at class initialization and closing it in a `ShutdownHook`
3. Something I didn't think of

Comment: Use one of the many existing RestClient frameworks and configure the built-in connection pool in a way that works well for you (measure). You don't need a shutdown hook for that. Connections are closed when the process dies anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the Java best practice between

<sup>There are no "best practices".  Please read and contemplate [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)</sup>

> 1. Opening and closing the connection every time I make a request

That's inefficient, especially if you are talking to an HTTPS endpoint.

Also, if you accidentally fail to close the connection, there is a potential that you will leak resources.  It depends on *how* you open the connection.

> 2. Opening the connection at class initialization and closing it in a ShutdownHook.

OK but, don't need to close it in a shutdown hook.  All of your application's outstanding network connections will be closed *by the operating system* when your application exits.  Closing them explicitly is unnecessary.

> 3. Something I didn't think of ...

a.  Open the connection once at the start (in class initialization, via a singleton, whatever) ... and don't bother to close it.  (See above.)

b.  Use an HTTP client or REST client library that can manage a connection pool.  Especially if your application is multi-threaded, or if it talks to multiple HTTP or HTTPS endpoints.

Comment: "That's inefficient, especially if you are talking to an HTTPS endpoint." - I believe for the current moment ssl handshaking performance issues were somehow mitigated: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077 https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8202625

Comment: They can be mitigated, but that implies that the connection is not being closed.   Note that the OP used the phrase "opening and closing the **connection**".